# Custom width on UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a standard UINavigationController on he iPad, but I want to make it a specific width, not full screen.  How can I do this and where should I put this code?

The custom width may need to be different for different view controllers in the stack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can access all the viewcontrollers in the stack using

`[navigationController viewControllers]`

or access the current controller using

`[navigationController visibleViewController]`

so you can get the controller of your interest and make a specific widht editing the frame of the view controller

you can put the code in `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol
implementing this method

```
– navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
```